# Filter a Laravel collection by date

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

In the code given below `$allZip["assigned_date"]` has value `2016-07-27 18:12:26`. When I try to compare it with the `created_at` field which is a timestamp field as well, the result is an empty collection.

```
$filtered_datas = $datas->filter(function ($data) use($allZip) {
    return $data->zip == $allZip["zip"] && $data->created_at < $allZip["assigned_date"];
});
```

There is data in database with `zip` field matching value from `$allZip["zip"]` and `created_at` field with value `2016-07-19 18:12:26`. So it should return one item in the collection but returns an empty collection instead. Why?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that all your dates is `DateTime` or `Carbon` instances, not strings. Otherwise, comparison operator shouldn't working as you expected.